# Atom editor does not reload changed file

Tags: git, atom-editor, git-reset

I am using Atom editor on Windows 7. On the git shell when I run the command, `git reset --hard` ,  all the other editors reset/undo all the modified files. but if I am using ATOM editor, changes are retained. If I try to close the file in editor, Atom ask, file is changed, do you want to save the changes.

How can I force Atom to undo changes when files are modified externally.

Comment: Relevant discussion, including an alternate solution: https://discuss.atom.io/t/force-file-reload/11508/15

Answer (score 20):

According to https://discuss.atom.io/t/auto-reload-changed-files/8451/6, [FileWatcher](https://github.com/lwblackledge/file-watcher) is an Atom package which will do what you want.

Comment: I can't understand why this is not the default behaviour. I think it is terribly dangerous: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/13717

Comment: Even more annoying is I don't find anything to even manually force file reload.

Comment: i installed file watched but it didn't work

Comment: @shieldgenerator7 If you need help, feel free to post a question.

Answer (score 7):

A simple solution that works:

1) Just close the file being edited

2) Click "File->Reopen Last Item" to re-open it

Bingo!

For Atom versions 1.29+, you can just click "Fetch" on the bottom-right corner of the editor.

[image]

Comment: I think @Code-Apprentice was looking for an automatic way to do that

Comment: true. hard to even come up with these keystrokes. however, i doubt there is 'refresh' in atom. not worth the time to install any plugins to do this.

Comment: The keystrokes for this are the same as in many applications. `ctrl+w` then `ctrl+shift+t`.

Comment: I'm fine with this workaround, since I usually only have this issue with 1 file at a time.

The keystroke @7yl4r commented, makes this even better.

Comment: In newer versions of Atom, re-opening the last file includes unsaved changes you had in that file, it does not reload the actual file from disk.

Comment: @DankeXie The fetch button does a git fetch operation, it doesn't reload/revert the open file to the on-disk version.

Comment: precisely why atom is the sublime text of the poor, what a pity

Comment: This is hardly worthy of a `Bingo!`.  Further, *Fetch* will only work if the file is available in a remote repo.  `No Remote` is shown even if you have a local git repo backing the file.

Answer (score 7):

In order to *manually* force the reload of a file, paste the following lines in your `init.coffee` file (from [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/auto-reload-changed-files/8451/17)):

```
atom.commands.add "atom-workspace", "custom:revert-to-disk", ->
  atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().buffer.reload()
```

In your `keymap.cson` file, paste the following:

```
'atom-workspace':
  'f5': 'custom:revert-to-disk'
```

NOTE: Make sure you restart Atom after applying these changes.

Whenever a file has changed and is not automatically reloaded, go to the tab and press <kbd>F5</kbd>. The file is immediately reverted to the disk state **without prompt**. So be careful, any manual changes (if any) are also **irrecoverably lost**, but that is the purpose of any revert-to-disk-state functionality.

The `init.coffee` file is located in/ can be opened from Atom via (from [here](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/the-init-file/#platform-mac)):

- Linux: `~/.atom/init.coffee`; open in Atom from `Edit` > `Init.Script`
- Mac: `~/.atom/init.coffee`; open in Atom from `Atom` > `Init.Script`
- Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\.atom\init.coffee`; open in Atom from `File` > `Init.Script`

The `keymap.cson` file is located in/ can be opened from Atom via (from [here](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#customizing-keybindings)):

- Linux: `~/.atom/keymap.cson`; open in Atom from `Edit` > `Keymap`
- Mac: `~/.atom/keymap.cson`; open in Atom from `Atom` > `Keymap`
- Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\.atom\keymap.cson`; open in Atom from `File` > `Keymap`

Comment: Note: Don't forget to restart Atom after applying these changes